# How to reference item to count messages in inbox?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

A small error is preventing this counting code from operating.

```vb
Sub Count2
  Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As Object
  Dim Count As Integer
  Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("My Personal Emails").Folders("spam")
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox "No such folder."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  For Each MapiItem In MapiFolderInbox.Messages
  Select Case Weekday(MapiItem.TimeReceived)
    Case vbMonday
      Count = Count + 1
    End Select
  Next MapiItem

  MsgBox "Number of spam messages sent on a Monday: " & Count
End Sub
```

The error message:

> Run-time error '424':
> Object required

The debugger highlights the line:

```vb
For Each MapiItem In MapiFolderInbox.Messages
```

Comment: I'm not a VBA specialist but I think you need to declare `MapiItem` and `MapiFolderInbox` before using them.

Comment: Okay - I declare both of the above as objects. The error message has changed to: Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a working version:

```vb
Sub Count2()

Dim i As Integer, Count As Integer
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objNSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNSpace.Folders("My Personal Emails").Folders("spam")

Count = 0
For i = 1 To objFolder.Items.count

  If Weekday(objFolder.Items(i).ReceivedTime) = vbMonday Then
    Count = Count + 1
  End If

Next i

MsgBox "Number of spam messages sent on a Monday: " & Count

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like the OP wants to iterate through the Inbox messages -- not Spam messages. (Edit: actually, the message does indicate reference to the spam folder -- the MapiFolderInbox variable is the culprit then).

Comment: That looks very promising! Can't wait to check if it works - if it does I will report back.

Comment: It worked - in part. For one of the smaller folders it trotted out the respective counts with no problem. For some of the larger ones Outlook seriously struggled (10 minutes to count a folder of about 5,000 e-mails). However, and quite surprisingly, it seemed to get faster when subsequent searches were performed in the same folder. One of the largest folders produced an error message I have not encountered before.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will speed things up a bit, but try storing the `objFolder.Items.Count` on a variable before the loop. Something like `totalMessages = objFolder.Items.Count` and then `For i = 1 To totalMessages`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: -- it seems you wish to count Spam messages, judging by the last string in your VBA code. Going with @sitnik's solution seems the better approach.

MapiFolderInbox seems to be undefined -- try assigning it to your Inbox folder, something like:

```
 Set MapiFolderInbox = objnSpace.Folders("My Personal Emails").Folders("Inbox")
```

Also see: [Option Explicit On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)